# jQuery .get() does not seem to work

Tags: jquery, get

This works on my computer but not on the server. Console returns '[]':

```
$.get("images/GalleryImages.xml", function (xml) {

        // Parse the xml file and get data
        var xmldoc = $.parseXML(xml);
        $globalxml = $( xmldoc );
        console.log($globalxml);
    }
);
```

the *script.js* is in the home dir, along with the images folder.

I tried also replacing the get argument with the full url, but also nothing. Can I import the xml through the *index.html* file, which calls on *script.js*? This is so annoying. (Assume any sever modifications are not an option).

Comment: Take a look at the network tab in Chrome dev tools.

Comment: Is     xml     also empty?

Comment: Try specifying absolute url, not relative one?

Comment: Tried absolute url, nothing. No, the xml is not empty. Told you everything works locally, but not remotely.

Answer (score 0):

rockerist wrote:

> Assume any server modifications are not an option.
>   but still you should ask is the sever is serving the correct mime-type for xml

```
text/xml
```

other wise the ajax call could be failing in a way it doesn't when served from local
disk.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was somehow in the $.parseXML line. I checked the jQuery, changed it to newer and older versions, but nothing changed. Finally I just treated the $.get return as an object. That did the trick:

```
$.get("images/GalleryImages.xml", function (xml) {
    $globalxml = $(xml);
});
```